# Box2D DistanceSquared strage errors

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

The problem is that I want to make a chain shape with these
(Altrenating x y coord)

```
24.8:-17.1:24.7:-17.0:23.9:-16.2:30.5:-16.3:30.8:-16.4:31.2:-16.5:31.3:-16.8:31.2:-16.9:30.8:-17.0:30.5:-17.1
```

This it the erro

```
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin\javaw.exe
File: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/libgdx/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/jni/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2ChainShape.cpp, Line 66

Expression: b2DistanceSquared(vertices[i-1], vertices[i]) > 0.005f * 0.005f
```

According to this:[search DistanceSquare](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/19b99d964b3d3fc2844dd21ae1799b6649fbcc96/Box2D/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2ChainShape.cpp)

It means that one of my vertices are too close together. But which one?
                Code:

```
            FileHandle r = Gdx.files.internal("d31.txt");
            BufferedInputStream y = r.read(200);
            /*ByteBuffer k = new ByteBuffer();
            y.read(k.toArray());*/
            int v = 0;



            int t = 0;
            v = (y.read())+(y.read()<<8)+(y.read()<<16)+(y.read()<<24);


            while ( y.available() > 0 ) {







                /*new Logger("das").error(""+v);*/
                if ( v > 48<<16 ) {
                    v = (y.read())+(y.read()<<8)+(y.read()<<16)+(y.read()<<24);
                }
                while ( v < (0x00200000) && y.available() > 1 ) {

                    t = (y.read())+(y.read()<<8)+(y.read()<<16)+(y.read()<<24);

                if ( e.size > 1 ) {
                    if ( e.get(e.size-2) != v/10f && e.get(e.size-1) != t/10f ) {
                    e.add(v/10f);
                    e.add( t/10f );
                    }
                }

                else {
                    e.add(v/10f);
                    e.add(t/10f);
                }
                    v = (y.read())+(y.read()<<8)+(y.read()<<16)+(y.read()<<24);

                }


                if ( e.size > 0) {

                Logger b = new Logger("");
                b.setLevel(Logger.DEBUG+1);
                b.info("  "+""+e.toString(":"));
                //e.removeRange(e.size-2, e.size-1);
                s=new ChainShape();
                s.createChain(e.items);

                f.shape = s;


                //s = new ChainShape();
                //s.

                body.createFixture(f);
                PolygonShape c = new PolygonShape();
                c.setAsBox(100, 100);
                f.shape = c;
                body.createFixture(f);
                //body = world.createBody(bod);
                }

                e.truncate(0);
            }
```

File:

```
l00 ú   V˙˙˙ú   ]˙˙˙3  ]˙˙˙4  \˙˙˙7  \˙˙˙8  [˙˙˙;  [˙˙˙;  X˙˙˙9  X˙˙˙8  W˙˙˙5  W˙˙˙4  V˙˙˙l00 ú   ţţ˙˙ú   ˙˙˙4  ˙˙˙5  ˙˙˙8  ˙˙˙9  ˙˙˙;  ˙˙˙;   ˙˙˙9   ˙˙˙8  ˙ţ˙˙5  ˙ţ˙˙4  ţţ˙˙l00ř   U˙˙˙÷   V˙˙˙ď   V˙˙˙ď   ^˙˙˙0  ^˙˙˙1  ]˙˙˙3  ]˙˙˙4  \˙˙˙7  \˙˙˙8  [˙˙˙9  [˙˙˙9  X˙˙˙8  W˙˙˙5  W˙˙˙4  V˙˙˙2  V˙˙˙1  U˙˙˙l00ă   ˙˙˙â   ˙˙˙Ď   ˙˙˙Î   ˙˙˙Â   ˙˙˙Á   ˙˙˙ż   ˙˙˙ľ   ˙˙˙ą   ˙˙˙¸   ˙˙˙°   ˙˙˙Ż   ˙˙˙­   ˙˙˙¬   ˙˙˙Ş   ˙˙˙©   ˙˙˙§   ˙˙˙¦   ˙˙˙Ą   ˙˙˙¤   ˙˙˙Ł   ˙˙˙Ł   <˙˙˙¤   =˙˙˙¦   =˙˙˙§   >˙˙˙©   >˙˙˙Ş   ?˙˙˙¬   ?˙˙˙­   @˙˙˙Ż   @˙˙˙°   A˙˙˙·   A˙˙˙¸   B˙˙˙˝   B˙˙˙ľ   C˙˙˙Á   C˙˙˙Â   D˙˙˙Í   D˙˙˙Î   E˙˙˙á   E˙˙˙â   F˙˙˙ę   F˙˙˙ë   E˙˙˙ě   F˙˙˙í   E˙˙˙ü   E˙˙˙ý   D˙˙˙ţ   E˙˙˙˙   D˙˙˙  D˙˙˙  C˙˙˙  D˙˙˙  D˙˙˙  C˙˙˙%  C˙˙˙%  ?˙˙˙&  >˙˙˙(  >˙˙˙)  =˙˙˙)  ˙˙˙(  ˙˙˙&  ˙˙˙%  ˙˙˙%  ˙˙˙  ˙˙˙  ˙˙˙˙   ˙˙˙ţ   ˙˙˙í   ˙˙˙ě   ˙˙˙l00ď   ýţ˙˙ď   ˙˙˙ő   ˙˙˙ö   ˙˙˙1  ˙˙˙2  ˙˙˙4  ˙˙˙5  ˙˙˙8  ˙˙˙9  ˙˙˙9   ˙˙˙8  ˙ţ˙˙5  ˙ţ˙˙4  ţţ˙˙1  ţţ˙˙0  ýţ˙˙l00ţ   T˙˙˙ý   U˙˙˙ä   U˙˙˙ä   _˙˙˙   _˙˙˙!  ^˙˙˙"  _˙˙˙*  _˙˙˙+  ^˙˙˙0  ^˙˙˙1  ]˙˙˙3  ]˙˙˙4  \˙˙˙6  \˙˙˙6  W˙˙˙5  V˙˙˙2  V˙˙˙1  U˙˙˙/  U˙˙˙.  T˙˙˙l00Ţ   ˙˙˙Ý   ˙˙˙Ň   ˙˙˙Ń   ˙˙˙Î   ˙˙˙Í   ˙˙˙Ę   ˙˙˙É   ˙˙˙Ç   ˙˙˙Ć   ˙˙˙Ă   ˙˙˙Â   ˙˙˙ż   ˙˙˙ľ   ˙˙˙¶   ˙˙˙µ   ˙˙˙Ş   ˙˙˙©   ˙˙˙    ˙˙˙ź   ˙˙˙ť   ˙˙˙ś   ˙˙˙š   ˙˙˙™   ˙˙˙—   ˙˙˙–   ˙˙˙•   ˙˙˙”   ˙˙˙’   ˙˙˙‘   ˙˙˙Ź   ˙˙˙Ž   ˙˙˙Ť   ˙˙˙Ť   "˙˙˙Ś   #˙˙˙‹   #˙˙˙‹   8˙˙˙Ś   8˙˙˙Ť   9˙˙˙Ť   =˙˙˙Ž   =˙˙˙Ź   >˙˙˙‘   >˙˙˙’   ?˙˙˙“   ?˙˙˙”   @˙˙˙–   @˙˙˙—   A˙˙˙™   A˙˙˙š   B˙˙˙ś   B˙˙˙ť   C˙˙˙ž   C˙˙˙ź   D˙˙˙¨   D˙˙˙©   E˙˙˙µ   E˙˙˙¶   F˙˙˙˝   F˙˙˙ľ   G˙˙˙Á   G˙˙˙Â   H˙˙˙Ĺ   H˙˙˙Ć   I˙˙˙É   I˙˙˙Ę   J˙˙˙Í   J˙˙˙Î   K˙˙˙Ń   K˙˙˙Ň   L˙˙˙Ü   L˙˙˙Ý   M˙˙˙ß   M˙˙˙ŕ   L˙˙˙  L˙˙˙  K˙˙˙  L˙˙˙  L˙˙˙  K˙˙˙0  K˙˙˙0  G˙˙˙1  F˙˙˙2  F˙˙˙3  E˙˙˙6  E˙˙˙7  D˙˙˙:  D˙˙˙;  C˙˙˙?  C˙˙˙@  B˙˙˙C  B˙˙˙D  A˙˙˙G  A˙˙˙H  @˙˙˙K  @˙˙˙L  ?˙˙˙N  ?˙˙˙N  ˙˙˙M  ˙˙˙L  ˙˙˙I  ˙˙˙H  ˙˙˙D  ˙˙˙C  ˙˙˙@  ˙˙˙?  ˙˙˙<  ˙˙˙;  ˙˙˙8  ˙˙˙7  ˙˙˙3  ˙˙˙2  ˙˙˙1  ˙˙˙0  ˙˙˙0  ˙˙˙  ˙˙˙  ˙˙˙á   ˙˙˙ŕ   ˙˙˙l00ä   üţ˙˙ä   ˙˙˙ű   ˙˙˙ü   ˙˙˙-  ˙˙˙.  ˙˙˙1  ˙˙˙2  ˙˙˙4  ˙˙˙5  ˙˙˙6  ˙˙˙6  ˙ţ˙˙5  ˙ţ˙˙4  ţţ˙˙1  ţţ˙˙0  ýţ˙˙*  ýţ˙˙)  üţ˙˙l00ü   Ôţ˙˙ř   Řţ˙˙÷   Řţ˙˙Ů   öţ˙˙Ř   öţ˙˙×   ÷ţ˙˙Ô   ÷ţ˙˙Ó   řţ˙˙Ó   ˙˙˙Ď   ˙˙˙Ď   ˙˙˙Î   
˙˙˙Ë   
˙˙˙Ę   ˙˙˙Ç   ˙˙˙Ć   ˙˙˙Ă   ˙˙˙Â   ˙˙˙ż   ˙˙˙ľ   ˙˙˙´   ˙˙˙ł   ˙˙˙§   ˙˙˙¦   ˙˙˙›   ˙˙˙š   ˙˙˙   ˙˙˙Ź   ˙˙˙Ť   ˙˙˙Ś   ˙˙˙Š   ˙˙˙‰   ˙˙˙   ˙˙˙   ˙˙˙†   ˙˙˙   ˙˙˙‚   ˙˙˙   ˙˙˙~   ˙˙˙{   ˙˙˙z    ˙˙˙w    ˙˙˙v   !˙˙˙s   !˙˙˙r   "˙˙˙o   "˙˙˙n   #˙˙˙k   #˙˙˙k   8˙˙˙n   8˙˙˙o   9˙˙˙r   9˙˙˙s   :˙˙˙v   :˙˙˙w   ;˙˙˙z   ;˙˙˙{   <˙˙˙~   <˙˙˙   =˙˙˙‚   =˙˙˙   >˙˙˙†   >˙˙˙   @˙˙˙   D˙˙˙‰   D˙˙˙Š   E˙˙˙Ś   E˙˙˙Ť   F˙˙˙Ź   F˙˙˙   G˙˙˙™   G˙˙˙š   H˙˙˙¦   H˙˙˙§   I˙˙˙˛   I˙˙˙ł   J˙˙˙ľ   J˙˙˙ż   K˙˙˙Â   K˙˙˙Ă   L˙˙˙Ĺ   L˙˙˙Ć   M˙˙˙É   M˙˙˙Ę   N˙˙˙Î   N˙˙˙Ď   O˙˙˙Ď   P˙˙˙Ó   T˙˙˙Ó   c˙˙˙Ô   d˙˙˙×   d˙˙˙Ř   e˙˙˙Ů   e˙˙˙÷   ˙˙˙ř   ˙˙˙ü   ‡˙˙˙  ‡˙˙˙  †˙˙˙  †˙˙˙  …˙˙˙  …˙˙˙  „˙˙˙  „˙˙˙  ˙˙˙   ˙˙˙!  ‚˙˙˙#  ‚˙˙˙$  ˙˙˙&  ˙˙˙'  €˙˙˙*  €˙˙˙+  ˙˙˙-  ˙˙˙.  ~˙˙˙0  ~˙˙˙1  }˙˙˙3  }˙˙˙4  |˙˙˙4  x˙˙˙5  w˙˙˙5  l˙˙˙6  k˙˙˙6  `˙˙˙7  _˙˙˙6  ^˙˙˙6  U˙˙˙8  S˙˙˙<  S˙˙˙=  R˙˙˙@  R˙˙˙A  Q˙˙˙D  Q˙˙˙E  P˙˙˙H  P˙˙˙I  O˙˙˙M  O˙˙˙N  N˙˙˙Q  N˙˙˙R  M˙˙˙U  M˙˙˙V  L˙˙˙Y  L˙˙˙Z  K˙˙˙^  K˙˙˙_  J˙˙˙b  J˙˙˙c  I˙˙˙e  I˙˙˙f  H˙˙˙i  H˙˙˙j  G˙˙˙m  G˙˙˙n  F˙˙˙p  F˙˙˙q  E˙˙˙r  E˙˙˙s  D˙˙˙t  D˙˙˙u  C˙˙˙v  C˙˙˙w  B˙˙˙y  B˙˙˙z  A˙˙˙{  A˙˙˙|  @˙˙˙|  ˙˙˙{  ˙˙˙y  ˙˙˙x  ˙˙˙w  ˙˙˙v  ˙˙˙u  ˙˙˙t  ˙˙˙s  ˙˙˙r  ˙˙˙q  ˙˙˙p  ˙˙˙n  ˙˙˙m  ˙˙˙j  ˙˙˙i  ˙˙˙g  ˙˙˙f  ˙˙˙c  ˙˙˙b  ˙˙˙_  ˙˙˙^  ˙˙˙[  ˙˙˙Z  ˙˙˙V  ˙˙˙U  ˙˙˙R  ˙˙˙Q  
˙˙˙N  
˙˙˙M  ˙˙˙J  ˙˙˙I  ˙˙˙E  ˙˙˙D  
˙˙˙A  
˙˙˙@    ˙˙˙=    ˙˙˙<  ˙˙˙9  ˙˙˙8  ˙˙˙7  ˙˙˙6  ˙˙˙6  đţ˙˙5  ďţ˙˙5  ăţ˙˙4  âţ˙˙4  Ţţ˙˙1  Ţţ˙˙0  Ýţ˙˙.  Ýţ˙˙-  Üţ˙˙+  Üţ˙˙*  Űţ˙˙(  Űţ˙˙'  Úţ˙˙$  Úţ˙˙#  Ůţ˙˙!  Ůţ˙˙   Řţ˙˙  Řţ˙˙  ×ţ˙˙  ×ţ˙˙  Öţ˙˙  Öţ˙˙  Őţ˙˙  Őţ˙˙  Ôţ˙˙l00
  ąţ˙˙  şţ˙˙  şţ˙˙  ˝ţ˙˙  ˝ţ˙˙  Áţ˙˙  Áţ˙˙ţ   Ĺţ˙˙ý   Ĺţ˙˙ú   Čţ˙˙ů   Čţ˙˙ç   Úţ˙˙ç   Űţ˙˙Ń   ńţ˙˙Ń   őţ˙˙Đ   öţ˙˙Ń   ÷ţ˙˙Đ   řţ˙˙Î   řţ˙˙Í   ůţ˙˙Ę   ůţ˙˙É   úţ˙˙Ć   úţ˙˙Ĺ   űţ˙˙Ĺ   ˙ţ˙˙Á   ˙˙˙Á   ˙˙˙ż   ˙˙˙»   ˙˙˙ş   ˙˙˙®   ˙˙˙­   ˙˙˙ˇ   ˙˙˙      ˙˙˙     ˙˙˙—   
˙˙˙Ź   
˙˙˙Ž   ˙˙˙‡   ˙˙˙†   ˙˙˙   ˙˙˙‚   
˙˙˙   
˙˙˙€   ˙˙˙~   ˙˙˙}   ˙˙˙|   ˙˙˙{   ˙˙˙z   ˙˙˙y   ˙˙˙w   ˙˙˙v   ˙˙˙u   ˙˙˙t   ˙˙˙s   ˙˙˙r   ˙˙˙p   ˙˙˙o   ˙˙˙n   ˙˙˙m   ˙˙˙l   ˙˙˙k   ˙˙˙i   ˙˙˙i   ˙˙˙k   ˙˙˙l   ˙˙˙n   ˙˙˙o   ˙˙˙n   ˙˙˙k   ˙˙˙j   ˙˙˙g   ˙˙˙f   ˙˙˙c   ˙˙˙b   ˙˙˙_   ˙˙˙^   ˙˙˙[   ˙˙˙Z    ˙˙˙W    ˙˙˙V   !˙˙˙S   !˙˙˙R   "˙˙˙O   "˙˙˙N   #˙˙˙L   #˙˙˙K   $˙˙˙K   7˙˙˙L   8˙˙˙M   8˙˙˙N   9˙˙˙Q   9˙˙˙R   :˙˙˙U   :˙˙˙V   ;˙˙˙Y   ;˙˙˙Z   <˙˙˙^   <˙˙˙_   =˙˙˙b   =˙˙˙c   >˙˙˙f   >˙˙˙g   ?˙˙˙j   ?˙˙˙k   @˙˙˙n   @˙˙˙o   A˙˙˙n   B˙˙˙l   B˙˙˙k   C˙˙˙i   C˙˙˙i   D˙˙˙j   D˙˙˙k   E˙˙˙m   E˙˙˙n   F˙˙˙o   F˙˙˙p   G˙˙˙q   G˙˙˙r   H˙˙˙t   H˙˙˙u   I˙˙˙v   I˙˙˙w   J˙˙˙x   J˙˙˙y   K˙˙˙{   K˙˙˙|   L˙˙˙}   L˙˙˙~   M˙˙˙   M˙˙˙€   N˙˙˙‚   N˙˙˙   O˙˙˙…   O˙˙˙†   P˙˙˙Ž   P˙˙˙Ź   Q˙˙˙–   Q˙˙˙—   R˙˙˙ź   R˙˙˙    S˙˙˙¬   S˙˙˙­   T˙˙˙ş   T˙˙˙»   U˙˙˙ż   U˙˙˙Á   W˙˙˙Á   X˙˙˙Ĺ   \˙˙˙Ĺ   `˙˙˙Ć   a˙˙˙É   a˙˙˙Ę   b˙˙˙Í   b˙˙˙Î   c˙˙˙Đ   c˙˙˙Ń   d˙˙˙Đ   e˙˙˙Đ   f˙˙˙Ń   g˙˙˙Ń   j˙˙˙ĺ   ~˙˙˙ĺ   ˙˙˙ů   “˙˙˙ú   “˙˙˙ý   –˙˙˙ţ   –˙˙˙  š˙˙˙  š˙˙˙  ž˙˙˙  ž˙˙˙  ˘˙˙˙  ˘˙˙˙  ˇ˙˙˙  ˇ˙˙˙   ˙˙˙   ˙˙˙  ź˙˙˙  ź˙˙˙  ž˙˙˙  ž˙˙˙  ť˙˙˙  ť˙˙˙  ś˙˙˙   ś˙˙˙!  ›˙˙˙#  ›˙˙˙$  š˙˙˙&  š˙˙˙'  ™˙˙˙)  ™˙˙˙*  ˙˙˙,  ˙˙˙-  —˙˙˙/  —˙˙˙0  –˙˙˙2  –˙˙˙3  •˙˙˙5  •˙˙˙6  ”˙˙˙7  ”˙˙˙8  “˙˙˙9  “˙˙˙:  ’˙˙˙:  ˙˙˙9  ‡˙˙˙9  ~˙˙˙:  }˙˙˙:  w˙˙˙;  v˙˙˙;  q˙˙˙<  p˙˙˙<  k˙˙˙=  j˙˙˙=  e˙˙˙>  d˙˙˙>  _˙˙˙?  ^˙˙˙?  \˙˙˙@  [˙˙˙B  [˙˙˙C  Z˙˙˙E  Z˙˙˙F  Y˙˙˙I  Y˙˙˙J  X˙˙˙M  X˙˙˙N  W˙˙˙Q  W˙˙˙R  V˙˙˙T  V˙˙˙U  U˙˙˙V  U˙˙˙W  T˙˙˙X  T˙˙˙Y  S˙˙˙Z  S˙˙˙[  R˙˙˙\  R˙˙˙]  Q˙˙˙_  Q˙˙˙`  P˙˙˙a  P˙˙˙b  O˙˙˙c  O˙˙˙d  N˙˙˙e  N˙˙˙f  M˙˙˙g  M˙˙˙h  L˙˙˙j  L˙˙˙k  K˙˙˙l  K˙˙˙m  J˙˙˙n  J˙˙˙o  I˙˙˙p  I˙˙˙q  H˙˙˙r  H˙˙˙s  G˙˙˙t  G˙˙˙u  F˙˙˙w  F˙˙˙x  E˙˙˙y  E˙˙˙z  D˙˙˙{  D˙˙˙|  C˙˙˙|  ˙˙˙{  ˙˙˙z  ˙˙˙y  ˙˙˙x  ˙˙˙w  ˙˙˙u  ˙˙˙t  ˙˙˙s  ˙˙˙r  ˙˙˙q  ˙˙˙p  ˙˙˙o  ˙˙˙n  ˙˙˙m  ˙˙˙l  ˙˙˙j  ˙˙˙i  ˙˙˙h  ˙˙˙g  ˙˙˙f  ˙˙˙e  
˙˙˙d  
˙˙˙c  ˙˙˙b  ˙˙˙a  ˙˙˙`  ˙˙˙_  
˙˙˙]  
˙˙˙\    ˙˙˙[    ˙˙˙Z  ˙˙˙Y  ˙˙˙X  ˙˙˙W  ˙˙˙V  ˙˙˙U  ˙˙˙T  ˙˙˙R  ˙˙˙Q  ˙˙˙N  ˙˙˙M  ˙˙˙J  ˙˙˙I  ˙˙˙G  ˙˙˙F  ˙˙˙C  ˙˙˙B   ˙˙˙@   ˙˙˙?  ˙ţ˙˙?  ţţ˙˙>  ýţ˙˙>  öţ˙˙=  őţ˙˙=  ńţ˙˙<  đţ˙˙<  ëţ˙˙;  ęţ˙˙;  ĺţ˙˙:  äţ˙˙:  ßţ˙˙9  Ţţ˙˙9  Ôţ˙˙:  Óţ˙˙:  Éţ˙˙9  Čţ˙˙8  Čţ˙˙7  Çţ˙˙6  Çţ˙˙5  Ćţ˙˙3  Ćţ˙˙2  Ĺţ˙˙0  Ĺţ˙˙/  Äţ˙˙-  Äţ˙˙,  Ăţ˙˙*  Ăţ˙˙)  Âţ˙˙'  Âţ˙˙&  Áţ˙˙$  Áţ˙˙#  Ŕţ˙˙!  Ŕţ˙˙   żţ˙˙  żţ˙˙  ľţ˙˙  ľţ˙˙  ˝ţ˙˙  ˝ţ˙˙  Ľţ˙˙  Ľţ˙˙  »ţ˙˙  »ţ˙˙  şţ˙˙  şţ˙˙  ąţ˙˙l00/  zţ˙˙-  |ţ˙˙,  |ţ˙˙  ‰ţ˙˙  ‰ţ˙˙  —ţ˙˙  —ţ˙˙  ¤ţ˙˙  ¤ţ˙˙ó   ˛ţ˙˙ň   ˛ţ˙˙ä   Ŕţ˙˙ă   Ŕţ˙˙Ő   Îţ˙˙Ô   Îţ˙˙Ç   Űţ˙˙Ć   Űţ˙˙Á   ŕţ˙˙Á   ăţ˙˙Ŕ   äţ˙˙Ŕ   ôţ˙˙ż   őţ˙˙ż   űţ˙˙ľ   üţ˙˙»   üţ˙˙ş   ýţ˙˙ł   ýţ˙˙˛   ţţ˙˙¬   ţţ˙˙«   ˙ţ˙˙¤   ˙ţ˙˙Ł    ˙˙˙ť    ˙˙˙ś   ˙˙˙•   ˙˙˙”   ˙˙˙Ť   ˙˙˙Ś   ˙˙˙†   ˙˙˙…   ˙˙˙‚   ˙˙˙   ˙˙˙~   ˙˙˙}   ˙˙˙{   ˙˙˙z   ˙˙˙w   ˙˙˙v   ˙˙˙t   ˙˙˙s      ˙˙˙q    ˙˙˙p   
˙˙˙m   
˙˙˙l   ˙˙˙j   ˙˙˙i   ˙˙˙f   ˙˙˙e   
˙˙˙c   
˙˙˙b   ˙˙˙_   ˙˙˙^   ˙˙˙\   ˙˙˙[   ˙˙˙Y   ˙˙˙X   ˙˙˙V   ˙˙˙U   ˙˙˙S   ˙˙˙R   ˙˙˙Q   ˙˙˙P   ˙˙˙N   ˙˙˙M   ˙˙˙K   ˙˙˙J   ˙˙˙H   ˙˙˙G   ˙˙˙F   ˙˙˙E   ˙˙˙C   ˙˙˙B   ˙˙˙@   ˙˙˙?   ˙˙˙=   ˙˙˙<   ˙˙˙;   ˙˙˙:   ˙˙˙8   ˙˙˙7   ˙˙˙5   ˙˙˙4   ˙˙˙2   ˙˙˙1   ˙˙˙0   ˙˙˙/    ˙˙˙-    ˙˙˙,   !˙˙˙*   !˙˙˙)   "˙˙˙(   "˙˙˙'   #˙˙˙'   9˙˙˙)   9˙˙˙*   :˙˙˙,   :˙˙˙-   ;˙˙˙/   ;˙˙˙0   <˙˙˙1   <˙˙˙2   =˙˙˙4   =˙˙˙5   >˙˙˙6   >˙˙˙7   ?˙˙˙9   ?˙˙˙:   @˙˙˙<   @˙˙˙=   A˙˙˙?   A˙˙˙@   B˙˙˙A   B˙˙˙B   C˙˙˙D   C˙˙˙E   D˙˙˙G   D˙˙˙H   E˙˙˙J   E˙˙˙K   F˙˙˙M   F˙˙˙N   G˙˙˙O   G˙˙˙P   H˙˙˙R   H˙˙˙S   I˙˙˙U   I˙˙˙V   J˙˙˙X   J˙˙˙Y   K˙˙˙Z   K˙˙˙[   L˙˙˙^   L˙˙˙_   M˙˙˙a   M˙˙˙b   N˙˙˙e   N˙˙˙f   O˙˙˙h   O˙˙˙i   P˙˙˙l   P˙˙˙m   Q˙˙˙o   Q˙˙˙p   R˙˙˙s   R˙˙˙t   S˙˙˙v   S˙˙˙w   T˙˙˙z   T˙˙˙{   U˙˙˙}   U˙˙˙~   V˙˙˙€   V˙˙˙   W˙˙˙„   W˙˙˙…   X˙˙˙Ś   X˙˙˙Ť   Y˙˙˙“   Y˙˙˙”   Z˙˙˙›   Z˙˙˙ś   [˙˙˙Ł   [˙˙˙¤   \˙˙˙Ş   \˙˙˙«   ]˙˙˙˛   ]˙˙˙ł   ^˙˙˙ş   ^˙˙˙»   _˙˙˙ľ   _˙˙˙ż   `˙˙˙ż   f˙˙˙Ŕ   g˙˙˙Ŕ   x˙˙˙Á   y˙˙˙Á   {˙˙˙Ć   €˙˙˙Ç   €˙˙˙Ő   Ž˙˙˙Ö   Ž˙˙˙ä   ś˙˙˙ĺ   ś˙˙˙ň   ©˙˙˙ó   ©˙˙˙  ·˙˙˙  ·˙˙˙  Ĺ˙˙˙  Ĺ˙˙˙  Ň˙˙˙  Ň˙˙˙,  ß˙˙˙-  ß˙˙˙/  á˙˙˙1  á˙˙˙2  ŕ˙˙˙3  ŕ˙˙˙4  ß˙˙˙5  ß˙˙˙6  Ţ˙˙˙8  Ţ˙˙˙9  Ý˙˙˙:  Ý˙˙˙;  Ü˙˙˙<  Ü˙˙˙=  Ű˙˙˙>  Ű˙˙˙?  Ú˙˙˙A  Ú˙˙˙B  Ů˙˙˙C  Ů˙˙˙D  Ř˙˙˙E  Ř˙˙˙F  ×˙˙˙G  ×˙˙˙H  Ö˙˙˙I  Ö˙˙˙J  Ő˙˙˙L  Ő˙˙˙M  Ô˙˙˙N  Ô˙˙˙O  Ó˙˙˙P  Ó˙˙˙Q  Ň˙˙˙R  Ň˙˙˙S  Ń˙˙˙U  Ń˙˙˙V  Đ˙˙˙W  Đ˙˙˙X  Ď˙˙˙Y  Ď˙˙˙Z  Î˙˙˙[  Î˙˙˙[  Í˙˙˙Z  Ě˙˙˙Z  Ç˙˙˙Y  Ć˙˙˙Y  Á˙˙˙X  Ŕ˙˙˙X  »˙˙˙W  ş˙˙˙W  µ˙˙˙V  ´˙˙˙V  Ż˙˙˙U  ®˙˙˙U  ©˙˙˙T  ¨˙˙˙T  ˘˙˙˙S  ˇ˙˙˙S  ś˙˙˙R  ›˙˙˙R  ˙˙˙Q  —˙˙˙Q  ’˙˙˙P  ‘˙˙˙P  Ś˙˙˙O  ‹˙˙˙O  †˙˙˙N  …˙˙˙N  €˙˙˙M  ˙˙˙M  z˙˙˙L  y˙˙˙L  t˙˙˙K  s˙˙˙K  n˙˙˙J  m˙˙˙J  g˙˙˙I  f˙˙˙I  a˙˙˙H  `˙˙˙H  ]˙˙˙J  [˙˙˙L  [˙˙˙M  Z˙˙˙N  Z˙˙˙O  Y˙˙˙P  Y˙˙˙Q  X˙˙˙R  X˙˙˙S  W˙˙˙T  W˙˙˙U  V˙˙˙W  V˙˙˙X  U˙˙˙Y  U˙˙˙Z  T˙˙˙[  T˙˙˙\  S˙˙˙]  S˙˙˙^  R˙˙˙_  R˙˙˙`  Q˙˙˙b  Q˙˙˙c  P˙˙˙d  P˙˙˙e  O˙˙˙f  O˙˙˙g  N˙˙˙h  N˙˙˙i  M˙˙˙j  M˙˙˙k  L˙˙˙m  L˙˙˙n  K˙˙˙o  K˙˙˙p  J˙˙˙q  J˙˙˙r  I˙˙˙s  I˙˙˙t  H˙˙˙u  H˙˙˙v  G˙˙˙x  G˙˙˙y  F˙˙˙z  F˙˙˙{  E˙˙˙|  E˙˙˙|  ˙˙˙{  ˙˙˙z  ˙˙˙y  ˙˙˙x  ˙˙˙v  ˙˙˙u  ˙˙˙t  ˙˙˙s  ˙˙˙r  ˙˙˙q  ˙˙˙p  ˙˙˙o  ˙˙˙n  ˙˙˙m  ˙˙˙k  ˙˙˙j  ˙˙˙i  ˙˙˙h  
˙˙˙g  
˙˙˙f  ˙˙˙e  ˙˙˙d  ˙˙˙c  ˙˙˙b  
˙˙˙`  
˙˙˙_    ˙˙˙^    ˙˙˙]  ˙˙˙\  ˙˙˙[  ˙˙˙Z  ˙˙˙Y  ˙˙˙W  ˙˙˙V  ˙˙˙U  ˙˙˙T  ˙˙˙S  ˙˙˙R  ˙˙˙Q  ˙˙˙P  ˙˙˙O  ˙˙˙N  ˙˙˙L  ˙˙˙K   ˙˙˙J   ˙˙˙H  ţţ˙˙H  úţ˙˙I  ůţ˙˙I  ôţ˙˙J  óţ˙˙J  îţ˙˙K  íţ˙˙K  čţ˙˙L  çţ˙˙L  âţ˙˙M  áţ˙˙M  Üţ˙˙N  Űţ˙˙N  Öţ˙˙O  Őţ˙˙O  Ńţ˙˙P  Đţ˙˙P  Ëţ˙˙Q  Ęţ˙˙Q  Ĺţ˙˙R  Äţ˙˙R  żţ˙˙S  ľţ˙˙S  ąţ˙˙T  ¸ţ˙˙T  łţ˙˙U  ˛ţ˙˙U  ­ţ˙˙V  ¬ţ˙˙V  §ţ˙˙W  ¦ţ˙˙W  ˇţ˙˙X   ţ˙˙X  śţ˙˙Y  ›ţ˙˙Y  –ţ˙˙Z  •ţ˙˙Z  ţ˙˙[  Źţ˙˙[  Ťţ˙˙Z  Ťţ˙˙Y  Śţ˙˙X  Śţ˙˙W  ‹ţ˙˙V  ‹ţ˙˙U  Šţ˙˙S  Šţ˙˙R  ‰ţ˙˙Q  ‰ţ˙˙P  ţ˙˙O  ţ˙˙N  ‡ţ˙˙M  ‡ţ˙˙L  †ţ˙˙J  †ţ˙˙H  „ţ˙˙F  „ţ˙˙E  ţ˙˙D  ţ˙˙C  ‚ţ˙˙B  ‚ţ˙˙A  ţ˙˙?  ţ˙˙>  €ţ˙˙=  €ţ˙˙<  ţ˙˙;  ţ˙˙:  ~ţ˙˙9  ~ţ˙˙8  }ţ˙˙6  }ţ˙˙4  {ţ˙˙2  {ţ˙˙1  zţ˙˙l00/  zţ˙˙.  {ţ˙˙-  {ţ˙˙  ‰ţ˙˙  ‰ţ˙˙  —ţ˙˙  —ţ˙˙  ¤ţ˙˙  ¤ţ˙˙ó   ˛ţ˙˙ň   ˛ţ˙˙ä   Ŕţ˙˙ă   Ŕţ˙˙Ő   Îţ˙˙Ô   Îţ˙˙Ç   Űţ˙˙Ć   Űţ˙˙Á   ŕţ˙˙Á   ăţ˙˙Ŕ   äţ˙˙Ŕ   ôţ˙˙ż   őţ˙˙ż   űţ˙˙ľ   üţ˙˙»   üţ˙˙ş   ýţ˙˙ł   ýţ˙˙˛   ţţ˙˙¬   ţţ˙˙«   ˙ţ˙˙¤   ˙ţ˙˙Ł    ˙˙˙ť    ˙˙˙ś   ˙˙˙•   ˙˙˙”   ˙˙˙Ť   ˙˙˙Ś   ˙˙˙†   ˙˙˙…   ˙˙˙‚   ˙˙˙   ˙˙˙~   ˙˙˙}   ˙˙˙{   ˙˙˙z   ˙˙˙w   ˙˙˙v   ˙˙˙t   ˙˙˙s      ˙˙˙q    ˙˙˙p   
˙˙˙m   
˙˙˙l   ˙˙˙j   ˙˙˙i   ˙˙˙f   ˙˙˙e   
˙˙˙c   
˙˙˙b   ˙˙˙_   ˙˙˙^   ˙˙˙\   ˙˙˙[   ˙˙˙X   ˙˙˙W   ˙˙˙U   ˙˙˙T   ˙˙˙Q   ˙˙˙P   ˙˙˙N   ˙˙˙M   ˙˙˙K   ˙˙˙J   ˙˙˙G   ˙˙˙F   ˙˙˙D   ˙˙˙C   ˙˙˙@   ˙˙˙?   ˙˙˙=   ˙˙˙<   ˙˙˙9   ˙˙˙8   ˙˙˙6   ˙˙˙5   ˙˙˙2   ˙˙˙1   ˙˙˙/   ˙˙˙.   ˙˙˙+   ˙˙˙*   ˙˙˙(   ˙˙˙'   ˙˙˙'   <˙˙˙(   =˙˙˙*   =˙˙˙+   >˙˙˙.   >˙˙˙/   ?˙˙˙1   ?˙˙˙2   @˙˙˙4   @˙˙˙5   A˙˙˙8   A˙˙˙9   B˙˙˙;   B˙˙˙<   C˙˙˙?   C˙˙˙@   D˙˙˙B   D˙˙˙C   E˙˙˙F   E˙˙˙G   F˙˙˙I   F˙˙˙J   G˙˙˙M   G˙˙˙N   H˙˙˙P   H˙˙˙Q   I˙˙˙T   I˙˙˙U   J˙˙˙W   J˙˙˙X   K˙˙˙Z   K˙˙˙[   L˙˙˙^   L˙˙˙_   M˙˙˙a   M˙˙˙b   N˙˙˙e   N˙˙˙f   O˙˙˙h   O˙˙˙i   P˙˙˙l   P˙˙˙m   Q˙˙˙o   Q˙˙˙p   R˙˙˙s   R˙˙˙t   S˙˙˙v   S˙˙˙w   T˙˙˙z   T˙˙˙{   U˙˙˙}   U˙˙˙~   V˙˙˙€   V˙˙˙   W˙˙˙„   W˙˙˙…   X˙˙˙Ś   X˙˙˙Ť   Y˙˙˙“   Y˙˙˙”   Z˙˙˙›   Z˙˙˙ś   [˙˙˙Ł   [˙˙˙¤   \˙˙˙Ş   \˙˙˙«   ]˙˙˙˛   ]˙˙˙ł   ^˙˙˙ş   ^˙˙˙»   _˙˙˙ľ   _˙˙˙ż   `˙˙˙ż   f˙˙˙Ŕ   g˙˙˙Ŕ   x˙˙˙Á   y˙˙˙Á   {˙˙˙Ć   €˙˙˙Ç   €˙˙˙Ő   Ž˙˙˙Ö   Ž˙˙˙ä   ś˙˙˙ĺ   ś˙˙˙ň   ©˙˙˙ó   ©˙˙˙  ·˙˙˙  ·˙˙˙  Ĺ˙˙˙  Ĺ˙˙˙  Ň˙˙˙  Ň˙˙˙-  ŕ˙˙˙.  ŕ˙˙˙/  á˙˙˙1  á˙˙˙2  ŕ˙˙˙3  ŕ˙˙˙4  ß˙˙˙5  ß˙˙˙6  Ţ˙˙˙8  Ţ˙˙˙9  Ý˙˙˙:  Ý˙˙˙;  Ü˙˙˙<  Ü˙˙˙=  Ű˙˙˙>  Ű˙˙˙?  Ú˙˙˙A  Ú˙˙˙B  Ů˙˙˙C  Ů˙˙˙D  Ř˙˙˙E  Ř˙˙˙F  ×˙˙˙G  ×˙˙˙H  Ö˙˙˙I  Ö˙˙˙J  Ő˙˙˙L  Ő˙˙˙M  Ô˙˙˙N  Ô˙˙˙O  Ó˙˙˙P  Ó˙˙˙Q  Ň˙˙˙R  Ň˙˙˙S  Ń˙˙˙U  Ń˙˙˙V  Đ˙˙˙W  Đ˙˙˙X  Ď˙˙˙Y  Ď˙˙˙Z  Î˙˙˙[  Î˙˙˙[  Í˙˙˙Z  Ě˙˙˙Z  Ç˙˙˙Y  Ć˙˙˙Y  Á˙˙˙X  Ŕ˙˙˙X  »˙˙˙W  ş˙˙˙W  µ˙˙˙V  ´˙˙˙V  Ż˙˙˙U  ®˙˙˙U  ©˙˙˙T  ¨˙˙˙T  ˘˙˙˙S  ˇ˙˙˙S  ś˙˙˙R  ›˙˙˙R  ˙˙˙Q  —˙˙˙Q  ’˙˙˙P  ‘˙˙˙P  Ś˙˙˙O  ‹˙˙˙O  †˙˙˙N  …˙˙˙N  €˙˙˙M  ˙˙˙M  z˙˙˙L  y˙˙˙L  t˙˙˙K  s˙˙˙K  n˙˙˙J  m˙˙˙J  g˙˙˙I  f˙˙˙I  a˙˙˙H  `˙˙˙H  ]˙˙˙J  [˙˙˙L  [˙˙˙M  Z˙˙˙N  Z˙˙˙O  Y˙˙˙P  Y˙˙˙Q  X˙˙˙R  X˙˙˙S  W˙˙˙T  W˙˙˙U  V˙˙˙W  V˙˙˙X  U˙˙˙Y  U˙˙˙Z  T˙˙˙[  T˙˙˙\  S˙˙˙]  S˙˙˙^  R˙˙˙_  R˙˙˙`  Q˙˙˙b  Q˙˙˙c  P˙˙˙d  P˙˙˙e  O˙˙˙f  O˙˙˙g  N˙˙˙h  N˙˙˙i  M˙˙˙j  M˙˙˙k  L˙˙˙m  L˙˙˙n  K˙˙˙o  K˙˙˙p  J˙˙˙q  J˙˙˙r  I˙˙˙s  I˙˙˙t  H˙˙˙u  H˙˙˙v  G˙˙˙x  G˙˙˙y  F˙˙˙z  F˙˙˙{  E˙˙˙|  E˙˙˙|  ˙˙˙{  ˙˙˙z  ˙˙˙y  ˙˙˙x  ˙˙˙v  ˙˙˙u  ˙˙˙t  ˙˙˙s  ˙˙˙r  ˙˙˙q  ˙˙˙p  ˙˙˙o  ˙˙˙n  ˙˙˙m  ˙˙˙k  ˙˙˙j  ˙˙˙i  ˙˙˙h  
˙˙˙g  
˙˙˙f  ˙˙˙e  ˙˙˙d  ˙˙˙c  ˙˙˙b  
˙˙˙`  
˙˙˙_    ˙˙˙^    ˙˙˙]  ˙˙˙\  ˙˙˙[  ˙˙˙Z  ˙˙˙Y  ˙˙˙W  ˙˙˙V  ˙˙˙U  ˙˙˙T  ˙˙˙S  ˙˙˙R  ˙˙˙Q  ˙˙˙P  ˙˙˙O  ˙˙˙N  ˙˙˙L  ˙˙˙K   ˙˙˙J   ˙˙˙H  ţţ˙˙H  úţ˙˙I  ůţ˙˙I  ôţ˙˙J  óţ˙˙J  îţ˙˙K  íţ˙˙K  čţ˙˙L  çţ˙˙L  âţ˙˙M  áţ˙˙M  Üţ˙˙N  Űţ˙˙N  Öţ˙˙O  Őţ˙˙O  Ńţ˙˙P  Đţ˙˙P  Ëţ˙˙Q  Ęţ˙˙Q  Ĺţ˙˙R  Äţ˙˙R  żţ˙˙S  ľţ˙˙S  ąţ˙˙T  ¸ţ˙˙T  łţ˙˙U  ˛ţ˙˙U  ­ţ˙˙V  ¬ţ˙˙V  §ţ˙˙W  ¦ţ˙˙W  ˇţ˙˙X   ţ˙˙X  śţ˙˙Y  ›ţ˙˙Y  –ţ˙˙Z  •ţ˙˙Z  ţ˙˙[  Źţ˙˙[  Ťţ˙˙Z  Ťţ˙˙Y  Śţ˙˙X  Śţ˙˙W  ‹ţ˙˙V  ‹ţ˙˙U  Šţ˙˙S  Šţ˙˙R  ‰ţ˙˙Q  ‰ţ˙˙P  ţ˙˙O  ţ˙˙N  ‡ţ˙˙M  ‡ţ˙˙L  †ţ˙˙J  †ţ˙˙H  „ţ˙˙F  „ţ˙˙E  ţ˙˙D  ţ˙˙C  ‚ţ˙˙B  ‚ţ˙˙A  ţ˙˙?  ţ˙˙>  €ţ˙˙=  €ţ˙˙<  ţ˙˙;  ţ˙˙:  ~ţ˙˙9  ~ţ˙˙8  }ţ˙˙6  }ţ˙˙4  {ţ˙˙2  {ţ˙˙1  zţ˙˙l00/  zţ˙˙.  {ţ˙˙-  {ţ˙˙  ‰ţ˙˙  ‰ţ˙˙  —ţ˙˙  —ţ˙˙  ¤ţ˙˙  ¤ţ˙˙ó   ˛ţ˙˙ň   ˛ţ˙˙ä   Ŕţ˙˙ă   Ŕţ˙˙Ő   Îţ˙˙Ô   Îţ˙˙Ç   Űţ˙˙Ć   Űţ˙˙Á   ŕţ˙˙Á   ăţ˙˙Ŕ   äţ˙˙Ŕ   ôţ˙˙ż   őţ˙˙ż   űţ˙˙ľ   üţ˙˙»   üţ˙˙ş   ýţ˙˙ł   ýţ˙˙˛   ţţ˙˙¬   ţţ˙˙«   ˙ţ˙˙¤   ˙ţ˙˙Ł    ˙˙˙ť    ˙˙˙ś   ˙˙˙•   ˙˙˙”   ˙˙˙Ť   ˙˙˙Ś   ˙˙˙†   ˙˙˙…   ˙˙˙‚   ˙˙˙   ˙˙˙~   ˙˙˙}   ˙˙˙{   ˙˙˙z   ˙˙˙w   ˙˙˙v   ˙˙˙t   ˙˙˙s      ˙˙˙q    ˙˙˙p   
˙˙˙m   
˙˙˙l   ˙˙˙j   ˙˙˙i   ˙˙˙f   ˙˙˙e   
˙˙˙c   
˙˙˙b   ˙˙˙_   ˙˙˙^   ˙˙˙\   ˙˙˙[   ˙˙˙X   ˙˙˙W   ˙˙˙U   ˙˙˙T   ˙˙˙Q   ˙˙˙P   ˙˙˙N   ˙˙˙M   ˙˙˙K   ˙˙˙J   ˙˙˙G   ˙˙˙F   ˙˙˙D   ˙˙˙C   ˙˙˙@   ˙˙˙?   ˙˙˙=   ˙˙˙<   ˙˙˙9   ˙˙˙8   ˙˙˙6   ˙˙˙5   ˙˙˙2   ˙˙˙1   ˙˙˙/   ˙˙˙.   ˙˙˙+   ˙˙˙*   ˙˙˙(   ˙˙˙'   ˙˙˙'   <˙˙˙(   =˙˙˙*   =˙˙˙+   >˙˙˙.   >˙˙˙/   ?˙˙˙1   ?˙˙˙2   @˙˙˙4   @˙˙˙5   A˙˙˙8   A˙˙˙9   B˙˙˙;   B˙˙˙<   C˙˙˙?   C˙˙˙@   D˙˙˙B   D˙˙˙C   E˙˙˙F   E˙˙˙G   F˙˙˙I   F˙˙˙J   G˙˙˙M   G˙˙˙N   H˙˙˙P   H˙˙˙Q   I˙˙˙T   I˙˙˙U   J˙˙˙W   J˙˙˙X   K˙˙˙Z   K˙˙˙[   L˙˙˙^   L˙˙˙_   M˙˙˙a   M˙˙˙b   N˙˙˙e   N˙˙˙f   O˙˙˙h   O˙˙˙i   P˙˙˙l   P˙˙˙m   Q˙˙˙o   Q˙˙˙p   R˙˙˙s   R˙˙˙t   S˙˙˙v   S˙˙˙w   T˙˙˙z   T˙˙˙{   U˙˙˙}   U˙˙˙~   V˙˙˙€   V˙˙˙   W˙˙˙„   W˙˙˙…   X˙˙˙Ś   X˙˙˙Ť   Y˙˙˙“   Y˙˙˙”   Z˙˙˙›   Z˙˙˙ś   [˙˙˙Ł   [˙˙˙¤   \˙˙˙Ş   \˙˙˙«   ]˙˙˙˛   ]˙˙˙ł   ^˙˙˙ş   ^˙˙˙»   _˙˙˙ľ   _˙˙˙ż   `˙˙˙ż   f˙˙˙Ŕ   g˙˙˙Ŕ   x˙˙˙Á   y˙˙˙Á   {˙˙˙Ć   €˙˙˙Ç   €˙˙˙Ő   Ž˙˙˙Ö   Ž˙˙˙ä   ś˙˙˙ĺ   ś˙˙˙ň   ©˙˙˙ó   ©˙˙˙  ·˙˙˙  ·˙˙˙  Ĺ˙˙˙  Ĺ˙˙˙  Ň˙˙˙  Ň˙˙˙-  ŕ˙˙˙.  ŕ˙˙˙/  á˙˙˙1  á˙˙˙2  ŕ˙˙˙3  ŕ˙˙˙4  ß˙˙˙5  ß˙˙˙6  Ţ˙˙˙8  Ţ˙˙˙9  Ý˙˙˙:  Ý˙˙˙;  Ü˙˙˙<  Ü˙˙˙=  Ű˙˙˙>  Ű˙˙˙?  Ú˙˙˙A  Ú˙˙˙B  Ů˙˙˙C  Ů˙˙˙D  Ř˙˙˙E  Ř˙˙˙F  ×˙˙˙G  ×˙˙˙H  Ö˙˙˙I  Ö˙˙˙J  Ő˙˙˙L  Ő˙˙˙M  Ô˙˙˙N  Ô˙˙˙O  Ó˙˙˙P  Ó˙˙˙Q  Ň˙˙˙R  Ň˙˙˙S  Ń˙˙˙U  Ń˙˙˙V  Đ˙˙˙W  Đ˙˙˙X  Ď˙˙˙Y  Ď˙˙˙Z  Î˙˙˙[  Î˙˙˙[  Í˙˙˙Z  Ě˙˙˙Z  Ç˙˙˙Y  Ć˙˙˙Y  Á˙˙˙X  Ŕ˙˙˙X  »˙˙˙W  ş˙˙˙W  µ˙˙˙V  ´˙˙˙V  Ż˙˙˙U  ®˙˙˙U  ©˙˙˙T  ¨˙˙˙T  ˘˙˙˙S  ˇ˙˙˙S  ś˙˙˙R  ›˙˙˙R  ˙˙˙Q  —˙˙˙Q  ’˙˙˙P  ‘˙˙˙P  Ś˙˙˙O  ‹˙˙˙O  †˙˙˙N  …˙˙˙N  €˙˙˙M  ˙˙˙M  z˙˙˙L  y˙˙˙L  t˙˙˙K  s˙˙˙K  n˙˙˙J  m˙˙˙J  g˙˙˙I  f˙˙˙I  a˙˙˙H  `˙˙˙H  ]˙˙˙J  [˙˙˙L  [˙˙˙M  Z˙˙˙N  Z˙˙˙O  Y˙˙˙P  Y˙˙˙Q  X˙˙˙R  X˙˙˙S  W˙˙˙T  W˙˙˙U  V˙˙˙W  V˙˙˙X  U˙˙˙Y  U˙˙˙Z  T˙˙˙[  T˙˙˙\  S˙˙˙]  S˙˙˙^  R˙˙˙_  R˙˙˙`  Q˙˙˙b  Q˙˙˙c  P˙˙˙d  P˙˙˙e  O˙˙˙f  O˙˙˙g  N˙˙˙h  N˙˙˙i  M˙˙˙j  M˙˙˙k  L˙˙˙m  L˙˙˙n  K˙˙˙o  K˙˙˙p  J˙˙˙q  J˙˙˙r  I˙˙˙s  I˙˙˙t  H˙˙˙u  H˙˙˙v  G˙˙˙x  G˙˙˙y  F˙˙˙z  F˙˙˙{  E˙˙˙|  E˙˙˙|  ˙˙˙{  ˙˙˙z  ˙˙˙y  ˙˙˙x  ˙˙˙v  ˙˙˙u  ˙˙˙t  ˙˙˙s  ˙˙˙r  ˙˙˙q  ˙˙˙p  ˙˙˙o  ˙˙˙n  ˙˙˙m  ˙˙˙k  ˙˙˙j  ˙˙˙i  ˙˙˙h  
˙˙˙g  
˙˙˙f  ˙˙˙e  ˙˙˙d  ˙˙˙c  ˙˙˙b  
˙˙˙`  
˙˙˙_    ˙˙˙^    ˙˙˙]  ˙˙˙\  ˙˙˙[  ˙˙˙Z  ˙˙˙Y  ˙˙˙W  ˙˙˙V  ˙˙˙U  ˙˙˙T  ˙˙˙S  ˙˙˙R  ˙˙˙Q  ˙˙˙P  ˙˙˙O  ˙˙˙N  ˙˙˙L  ˙˙˙K   ˙˙˙J   ˙˙˙H  ţţ˙˙H  úţ˙˙I  ůţ˙˙I  ôţ˙˙J  óţ˙˙J  îţ˙˙K  íţ˙˙K  čţ˙˙L  çţ˙˙L  âţ˙˙M  áţ˙˙M  Üţ˙˙N  Űţ˙˙N  Öţ˙˙O  Őţ˙˙O  Ńţ˙˙P  Đţ˙˙P  Ëţ˙˙Q  Ęţ˙˙Q  Ĺţ˙˙R  Äţ˙˙R  żţ˙˙S  ľţ˙˙S  ąţ˙˙T  ¸ţ˙˙T  łţ˙˙U  ˛ţ˙˙U  ­ţ˙˙V  ¬ţ˙˙V  §ţ˙˙W  ¦ţ˙˙W  ˇţ˙˙X   ţ˙˙X  śţ˙˙Y  ›ţ˙˙Y  –ţ˙˙Z  •ţ˙˙Z  ţ˙˙[  Źţ˙˙[  Ťţ˙˙Z  Ťţ˙˙Y  Śţ˙˙X  Śţ˙˙W  ‹ţ˙˙V  ‹ţ˙˙U  Šţ˙˙S  Šţ˙˙R  ‰ţ˙˙Q  ‰ţ˙˙P  ţ˙˙O  ţ˙˙N  ‡ţ˙˙M  ‡ţ˙˙L  †ţ˙˙J  †ţ˙˙H  „ţ˙˙F  „ţ˙˙E  ţ˙˙D  ţ˙˙C  ‚ţ˙˙B  ‚ţ˙˙A  ţ˙˙?  ţ˙˙>  €ţ˙˙=  €ţ˙˙<  ţ˙˙;  ţ˙˙:  ~ţ˙˙9  ~ţ˙˙8  }ţ˙˙6  }ţ˙˙4  {ţ˙˙2  {ţ˙˙1  zţ˙˙l00/  zţ˙˙.  {ţ˙˙-  {ţ˙˙  ‰ţ˙˙  ‰ţ˙˙  —ţ˙˙  —ţ˙˙  ¤ţ˙˙  ¤ţ˙˙î   ·ţ˙˙í   ·ţ˙˙×   Íţ˙˙Ö   Íţ˙˙Á   âţ˙˙Á   îţ˙˙Ŕ   ďţ˙˙Ŕ   űţ˙˙ż   üţ˙˙ľ   üţ˙˙˝   ýţ˙˙¸   ýţ˙˙·   ţţ˙˙ł   ţţ˙˙˛   ˙ţ˙˙­   ˙ţ˙˙¬    ˙˙˙§    ˙˙˙¦   ˙˙˙˘   ˙˙˙ˇ   ˙˙˙ś   ˙˙˙›   ˙˙˙—   ˙˙˙–   ˙˙˙‘   ˙˙˙   ˙˙˙‹   ˙˙˙Š   ˙˙˙†   ˙˙˙…   ˙˙˙   ˙˙˙€   ˙˙˙|   ˙˙˙{       ˙˙˙w    ˙˙˙v   
˙˙˙r   
˙˙˙q   ˙˙˙m   ˙˙˙l   ˙˙˙i   ˙˙˙h   
˙˙˙e   
˙˙˙d   ˙˙˙`   ˙˙˙_   ˙˙˙\   ˙˙˙[   ˙˙˙X   ˙˙˙W   ˙˙˙U   ˙˙˙T   ˙˙˙Q   ˙˙˙P   ˙˙˙N   ˙˙˙M   ˙˙˙K   ˙˙˙J   ˙˙˙G   ˙˙˙F   ˙˙˙D   ˙˙˙C   ˙˙˙@   ˙˙˙?   ˙˙˙=   ˙˙˙<   ˙˙˙9   ˙˙˙8   ˙˙˙6   ˙˙˙5   ˙˙˙2   ˙˙˙1   ˙˙˙/   ˙˙˙.   ˙˙˙+   ˙˙˙*   ˙˙˙(   ˙˙˙'   ˙˙˙'   <˙˙˙(   =˙˙˙*   =˙˙˙+   >˙˙˙.   >˙˙˙/   ?˙˙˙1   ?˙˙˙2   @˙˙˙4   @˙˙˙5   A˙˙˙8   A˙˙˙9   B˙˙˙;   B˙˙˙<   C˙˙˙?   C˙˙˙@   D˙˙˙B   D˙˙˙C   E˙˙˙F   E˙˙˙G   F˙˙˙I   F˙˙˙J   G˙˙˙M   G˙˙˙N   H˙˙˙P   H˙˙˙Q   I˙˙˙T   I˙˙˙U   J˙˙˙W   J˙˙˙X   K˙˙˙[   K˙˙˙\   L˙˙˙_   L˙˙˙`   M˙˙˙c   M˙˙˙d   N˙˙˙h   N˙˙˙i   O˙˙˙l   O˙˙˙m   P˙˙˙p   P˙˙˙q   Q˙˙˙u   Q˙˙˙v   R˙˙˙z   R˙˙˙{   S˙˙˙   S˙˙˙€   T˙˙˙„   T˙˙˙…   U˙˙˙Š   U˙˙˙‹   V˙˙˙Ź   V˙˙˙   W˙˙˙•   W˙˙˙–   X˙˙˙›   X˙˙˙ś   Y˙˙˙    Y˙˙˙ˇ   Z˙˙˙¦   Z˙˙˙§   [˙˙˙«   [˙˙˙¬   \˙˙˙±   \˙˙˙˛   ]˙˙˙·   ]˙˙˙¸   ^˙˙˙Ľ   ^˙˙˙˝   _˙˙˙ż   _˙˙˙Ŕ   `˙˙˙Ŕ   l˙˙˙Á   m˙˙˙Á   y˙˙˙×   Ź˙˙˙Ř   Ź˙˙˙î   Ą˙˙˙ď   Ą˙˙˙  ·˙˙˙  ·˙˙˙  Ĺ˙˙˙  Ĺ˙˙˙  Ň˙˙˙  Ň˙˙˙-  ŕ˙˙˙.  ŕ˙˙˙/  á˙˙˙0  á˙˙˙1  ŕ˙˙˙3  ŕ˙˙˙4  ß˙˙˙5  ß˙˙˙6  Ţ˙˙˙7  Ţ˙˙˙8  Ý˙˙˙9  Ý˙˙˙:  Ü˙˙˙<  Ü˙˙˙=  Ű˙˙˙>  Ű˙˙˙?  Ú˙˙˙@  Ú˙˙˙A  Ů˙˙˙B  Ů˙˙˙C  Ř˙˙˙D  Ř˙˙˙E  ×˙˙˙G  ×˙˙˙H  Ö˙˙˙I  Ö˙˙˙J  Ő˙˙˙K  Ő˙˙˙L  Ô˙˙˙M  Ô˙˙˙N  Ó˙˙˙P  Ó˙˙˙Q  Ň˙˙˙R  Ň˙˙˙S  Ń˙˙˙T  Ń˙˙˙U  Đ˙˙˙V  Đ˙˙˙W  Ď˙˙˙Y  Ď˙˙˙Z  Î˙˙˙Z  É˙˙˙Y  Č˙˙˙Y  Ă˙˙˙X  Â˙˙˙X  ˝˙˙˙W  Ľ˙˙˙W  ·˙˙˙V  ¶˙˙˙V  ±˙˙˙U  °˙˙˙U  «˙˙˙T  Ş˙˙˙T  Ł˙˙˙S  ˘˙˙˙S  ž˙˙˙R  ť˙˙˙R  ˙˙˙Q  —˙˙˙Q  ’˙˙˙P  ‘˙˙˙P  Ś˙˙˙O  ‹˙˙˙O  †˙˙˙N  …˙˙˙N  €˙˙˙M  ˙˙˙M  z˙˙˙L  y˙˙˙L  t˙˙˙K  s˙˙˙K  n˙˙˙J  m˙˙˙J  g˙˙˙I  f˙˙˙I  a˙˙˙H  `˙˙˙H  ]˙˙˙J  [˙˙˙L  [˙˙˙M  Z˙˙˙N  Z˙˙˙O  Y˙˙˙P  Y˙˙˙Q  X˙˙˙R  X˙˙˙S  W˙˙˙T  W˙˙˙U  V˙˙˙V  V˙˙˙W  U˙˙˙X  U˙˙˙Y  T˙˙˙Z  T˙˙˙[  S˙˙˙\  S˙˙˙]  R˙˙˙^  R˙˙˙`  P˙˙˙a  P˙˙˙b  O˙˙˙c  O˙˙˙d  N˙˙˙e  N˙˙˙f  M˙˙˙g  M˙˙˙h  L˙˙˙i  L˙˙˙k  J˙˙˙l  J˙˙˙m  I˙˙˙n  I˙˙˙o  H˙˙˙p  H˙˙˙q  G˙˙˙r  G˙˙˙t  E˙˙˙u  E˙˙˙v  D˙˙˙w  D˙˙˙x  C˙˙˙y  C˙˙˙z  B˙˙˙{  B˙˙˙|  A˙˙˙|  ˙˙˙{  ˙˙˙z  ˙˙˙y  ˙˙˙x  ˙˙˙w  ˙˙˙v  ˙˙˙u  ˙˙˙t  ˙˙˙r  ˙˙˙q  ˙˙˙p  ˙˙˙o  ˙˙˙n  ˙˙˙m  ˙˙˙l  ˙˙˙k  ˙˙˙i  ˙˙˙h  ˙˙˙g  ˙˙˙f  ˙˙˙e  
˙˙˙d  
˙˙˙c  ˙˙˙b  ˙˙˙a  ˙˙˙`  ˙˙˙^    ˙˙˙]    ˙˙˙\  ˙˙˙[  ˙˙˙Z  ˙˙˙Y  ˙˙˙X  ˙˙˙W  ˙˙˙V  ˙˙˙U  ˙˙˙T  ˙˙˙S  ˙˙˙R  ˙˙˙Q  ˙˙˙P  ˙˙˙O  ˙˙˙N  ˙˙˙L  ˙˙˙K   ˙˙˙J   ˙˙˙H  ţţ˙˙H  úţ˙˙I  ůţ˙˙I  ôţ˙˙J  óţ˙˙J  îţ˙˙K  íţ˙˙K  čţ˙˙L  çţ˙˙L  âţ˙˙M  áţ˙˙M  Üţ˙˙N  Űţ˙˙N  Öţ˙˙O  Őţ˙˙O  Đţ˙˙P  Ďţ˙˙P  Ęţ˙˙Q  Éţ˙˙Q  Äţ˙˙R  Ăţ˙˙R  ľţ˙˙S  ˝ţ˙˙S  ¸ţ˙˙T  ·ţ˙˙T  ˛ţ˙˙U  ±ţ˙˙U  ¬ţ˙˙V  «ţ˙˙V  ¦ţ˙˙W  Ąţ˙˙W  źţ˙˙X  žţ˙˙X  ™ţ˙˙Y  ţ˙˙Y  “ţ˙˙Z  ’ţ˙˙Z  Ťţ˙˙Y  Śţ˙˙W  Śţ˙˙V  ‹ţ˙˙U  ‹ţ˙˙T  Šţ˙˙S  Šţ˙˙R  ‰ţ˙˙Q  ‰ţ˙˙P  ţ˙˙N  ţ˙˙M  ‡ţ˙˙L  ‡ţ˙˙K  †ţ˙˙J  †ţ˙˙I  …ţ˙˙H  …ţ˙˙G  „ţ˙˙E  „ţ˙˙D  ţ˙˙C  ţ˙˙B  ‚ţ˙˙A  ‚ţ˙˙@  ţ˙˙?  ţ˙˙>  €ţ˙˙<  €ţ˙˙;  ţ˙˙:  ţ˙˙9  ~ţ˙˙8  ~ţ˙˙7  }ţ˙˙6  }ţ˙˙5  |ţ˙˙4  |ţ˙˙3  {ţ˙˙1  {ţ˙˙0  zţ˙˙l00    ÷   Íţ˙˙ő   Ďţ˙˙ô   Ďţ˙˙Ţ   ĺţ˙˙Ý   ĺţ˙˙Í   őţ˙˙Í   ţţ˙˙Ę   ˙˙˙É   ˙˙˙Ç   ˙˙˙Ľ   ˙˙˙»   ˙˙˙Ż   ˙˙˙®   ˙˙˙¦   ˙˙˙Ą   ˙˙˙ˇ   ˙˙˙    ˙˙˙›   ˙˙˙š   ˙˙˙•   ˙˙˙”     ˙˙˙     ˙˙˙Ź   
˙˙˙Š   
˙˙˙‰   ˙˙˙…   ˙˙˙„   ˙˙˙€   ˙˙˙   
˙˙˙{   
˙˙˙z   ˙˙˙v   ˙˙˙u   ˙˙˙q   ˙˙˙p   ˙˙˙l   ˙˙˙k   ˙˙˙g   ˙˙˙f   ˙˙˙b   ˙˙˙a   ˙˙˙]   ˙˙˙\   ˙˙˙X   ˙˙˙W   ˙˙˙S   ˙˙˙R   ˙˙˙O   ˙˙˙N   ˙˙˙J   ˙˙˙I   ˙˙˙F   ˙˙˙E   ˙˙˙B   ˙˙˙A   ˙˙˙=   ˙˙˙<   ˙˙˙9   ˙˙˙8   ˙˙˙5   ˙˙˙4   ˙˙˙0   ˙˙˙/   ˙˙˙,   ˙˙˙+   ˙˙˙(   ˙˙˙'    ˙˙˙'   ;˙˙˙(   <˙˙˙+   <˙˙˙,   =˙˙˙/   =˙˙˙0   >˙˙˙3   >˙˙˙4   ?˙˙˙8   ?˙˙˙9   @˙˙˙<   @˙˙˙=   A˙˙˙@   A˙˙˙A   B˙˙˙E   B˙˙˙F   C˙˙˙I   C˙˙˙J   D˙˙˙M   D˙˙˙N   E˙˙˙R   E˙˙˙S   F˙˙˙V   F˙˙˙W   G˙˙˙[   G˙˙˙\   H˙˙˙`   H˙˙˙a   I˙˙˙e   I˙˙˙f   J˙˙˙j   J˙˙˙k   K˙˙˙o   K˙˙˙p   L˙˙˙t   L˙˙˙u   M˙˙˙y   M˙˙˙z   N˙˙˙~   N˙˙˙   O˙˙˙   O˙˙˙„   P˙˙˙‰   P˙˙˙Š   Q˙˙˙Ž   Q˙˙˙Ź   R˙˙˙”   R˙˙˙•   S˙˙˙™   S˙˙˙š   T˙˙˙ź   T˙˙˙    U˙˙˙Ą   U˙˙˙¦   V˙˙˙­   V˙˙˙®   W˙˙˙ş   W˙˙˙»   X˙˙˙Ç   X˙˙˙É   Z˙˙˙Ę   Z˙˙˙Í   ]˙˙˙Í   f˙˙˙Ý   v˙˙˙Ţ   v˙˙˙ô   Ś˙˙˙ő   Ś˙˙˙÷   Ž˙˙˙ř   Ž˙˙˙ů   Ť˙˙˙ú   Ť˙˙˙ű   Ś˙˙˙ü   Ś˙˙˙ý   ‹˙˙˙ţ   ‹˙˙˙˙   Š˙˙˙   Š˙˙˙  ‰˙˙˙  ‰˙˙˙  ˙˙˙  ˙˙˙  ‡˙˙˙  ‡˙˙˙  …˙˙˙      …˙˙˙
  „˙˙˙  „˙˙˙  ˙˙˙
  ˙˙˙  ˙˙˙  ˙˙˙  €˙˙˙  €˙˙˙  ~˙˙˙  ~˙˙˙  }˙˙˙  }˙˙˙  |˙˙˙  |˙˙˙  z˙˙˙  z˙˙˙  y˙˙˙  y˙˙˙  x˙˙˙   x˙˙˙"  v˙˙˙#  v˙˙˙$  u˙˙˙%  u˙˙˙'  s˙˙˙(  s˙˙˙)  r˙˙˙*  r˙˙˙+  q˙˙˙,  q˙˙˙.  o˙˙˙/  o˙˙˙0  n˙˙˙1  n˙˙˙2  m˙˙˙3  m˙˙˙5  k˙˙˙6  k˙˙˙7  j˙˙˙8  j˙˙˙8  a˙˙˙7  `˙˙˙7  [˙˙˙8  Z˙˙˙9  Z˙˙˙:  Y˙˙˙;  Y˙˙˙<  X˙˙˙=  X˙˙˙>  W˙˙˙?  W˙˙˙A  U˙˙˙B  U˙˙˙C  T˙˙˙D  T˙˙˙E  S˙˙˙F  S˙˙˙G  R˙˙˙H  R˙˙˙J  P˙˙˙K  P˙˙˙L  O˙˙˙M  O˙˙˙N  N˙˙˙O  N˙˙˙P  M˙˙˙Q  M˙˙˙S  K˙˙˙T  K˙˙˙U  J˙˙˙V  J˙˙˙W  I˙˙˙X  I˙˙˙Y  H˙˙˙Z  H˙˙˙\  F˙˙˙]  F˙˙˙^  E˙˙˙^  ˙˙˙]  ˙˙˙\  ˙˙˙Z  ˙˙˙Y  ˙˙˙X  ˙˙˙W  ˙˙˙V  ˙˙˙U  ˙˙˙T  ˙˙˙S  ˙˙˙Q  ˙˙˙P  ˙˙˙O  
˙˙˙N  
˙˙˙M  ˙˙˙L  ˙˙˙K  ˙˙˙J  ˙˙˙H    ˙˙˙G    ˙˙˙F  ˙˙˙E  ˙˙˙D  ˙˙˙C  ˙˙˙B  ˙˙˙A  ˙˙˙@  ˙˙˙?  ˙˙˙=  ˙˙˙<  ˙˙˙;  ˙˙˙:  ˙˙˙9  ˙˙˙8  ˙˙˙7   ˙˙˙7  úţ˙˙8  ůţ˙˙8  óţ˙˙9  ňţ˙˙8  ńţ˙˙7  ńţ˙˙6  đţ˙˙5  đţ˙˙4  ďţ˙˙3  ďţ˙˙1  íţ˙˙0  íţ˙˙/  ěţ˙˙.  ěţ˙˙,  ęţ˙˙+  ęţ˙˙*  éţ˙˙)  éţ˙˙(  čţ˙˙'  čţ˙˙%  ćţ˙˙$  ćţ˙˙#  ĺţ˙˙"  ĺţ˙˙   ăţ˙˙  ăţ˙˙  âţ˙˙  âţ˙˙  ŕţ˙˙  ŕţ˙˙  ßţ˙˙  ßţ˙˙  Ţţ˙˙  Ţţ˙˙  Ýţ˙˙  Ýţ˙˙  Űţ˙˙  Űţ˙˙  Úţ˙˙  Úţ˙˙
  Řţ˙˙  Řţ˙˙  ×ţ˙˙
  ×ţ˙˙  Őţ˙˙  Őţ˙˙  Ôţ˙˙  Ôţ˙˙  Óţ˙˙  Óţ˙˙  Ňţ˙˙  Ňţ˙˙   Ńţ˙˙˙   Ńţ˙˙ţ   Đţ˙˙ý   Đţ˙˙ü   Ďţ˙˙ű   Ďţ˙˙ú   Îţ˙˙ů   Îţ˙˙ř   Íţ˙˙
```

Comment: "But which one" You have about 20 things in a list. Can you really not just look through the list?

Comment: How do you pass that string to... some code, in order to get the exception? As things stand, the problem is not reproducible.

Comment: I am sorry for th misunderstanding. It is a FloatArray the string is printed by the logger. So it is in float.
Code:

Comment: I still can't actually compile and run your code. You need an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please paste code in your question. Links die, making the question useless to those who find it later.

Answer (score 0):

I learned the hard way that you should never use items on float array... Always use toarray!